# Is it appropriate to suggest tag synonyms via posts on meta sites?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I occasionally come across tags I think should be synonyms of one another and am tempted to try to alert people to them by posting on the appropriate meta site.  So far I have held off though, assuming that it would be seen as trying to circumvent the reputation requirement.  That said, I have noticed questions on a couple meta sites that are effectively just tag synonym suggestions and would like to understand how they are perceived.

Are these kinds of questions generally considered appropriate or reluctantly accepted when the synonyms of sufficiently obvious?

Comment: Sometimes they are simply [necessary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305388/lets-handle-doomed-tag-synonym-suggestions).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Ah, that's a great point.  I've seen that post before and that's definitely an important special case.  I suppose, at least for the sake of further discussion, I'm interested in the cases where it could have been suggested by someone else but either hasn't been noticed by anyone who could or is not necessarily obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can speak for the Metas of both [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/) and [Genealogy & Family History](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchanges where we welcome discussions about tagging and encourage our users to propose tag synonyms.

I think it is only on the largest sites that there is a critical mass that enables synonyms to be voted into existence.

On [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/) Meta we created [Guidelines for proposing tag synonyms](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3820/guidelines-for-proposing-tag-synonyms).

Comment: Even SO doesn't reliably handle synonym suggestions without bringing them up on Meta, and there appears to be no hostility toward such posts there.